# Find Count of .XML Files in Directory / Sub-Directory

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have a directory with millions of sub directories with millions of sub directories and each directory may contain .XML files or another sub directory ... what I need is to count the number of .XML files in the parent directory in UNIX ...

I've tried a lot of this but ended up with listing them not counting them - Any ideas ??

Comment: Just confirming, are you using any Linux platform? Or is it really Windows + cmd? I didn't understand the unix quote lol

Comment: i am accessing server using unix

Comment: So the server is *nix, is it using Bash?

Comment: I'm also unclear. You just need a file count from the parent directory? Does that mean that the contents of the sub-directories aren't important? If that is the case, try looking at the man pages for `find`, `ls`, and `wc`. I don't have a full answer for you because I don't have a Unix environment in front of me to test.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're looking for the number of xml files on the *children* directories, not parent.  If so, this should do the trick:

```
find . -type f -name \*.xml | wc -l
```

Make sure you're on the top level directory from where you want to search.  It will display all files named `*.xml` and count the returned lines.